# How to write binary data in Python and read it in C?

Tags: c, python-3.x, io

I'm trying to write an array of integers into a binary file using Python and reading those values in C. I've tried the following code but the result is trash.

Python:

```
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import reduce

# s = np.random.uniform(0,500,1000)

mu, sigma = 1, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
n = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
n = [i * 1000 for i in n]
n = [int(round(i, 0)) for i in n]
n.sort()

with open('norm.bin', 'wb') as f:
    for e in n:
        f.write(struct.pack('i', e))
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5000

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    int norm[SIZE];

    file = fopen("norm.bin","rb");  
    fread(norm, sizeof(int), 1, file); 
    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", norm[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If anybody could help me I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: Why are you reading only 1 element and printing `SIZE` elements? Did you check the data file via binary editor, `od` command or something like them?

Comment: @MikeCAT because I'm stupid and didn't notice, thank you so much! It's working properly now!

Comment: 1. replace `1` with `SIZE`, 2. check the return value == `SIZE`, 3. Profit.

Comment: You have to clarify what "trash" is.

Comment: after `file=fopen(...)` you should always check that file is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `fread()` function is

```
fread(/*buffer*/, /*size of one element*/, /*number of elements*/, /*file pointer*/);
```

Therefore,

```
fread(norm, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

reads only one element and leave the other 4999 elements uninitialized.

Use

```
fread(norm, sizeof(int), SIZE, file);
```

to read `SIZE` elements.

`fread()` returns the number of elements read, so checking if the read is successful like

```
if (fread(norm, sizeof(int), SIZE, file) != SIZE) {
    fputs("fread() failed\n", stderr);
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
}
```

is better.

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of endian-ness issues here.

Consider using the Array module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

You specify the data format, but pass in native python types. Then it handles the conversion for you. It's an easier way of handing the translation than using the struct module.

e.x.

```
In [18]: a=array('h', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [19]: a.tostring()
Out[19]: '\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00'

In [20]: a.byteswap()

In [21]: a.tostring()
Out[21]: '\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05'
```

You can also use a.tofile() to write the bin data to a file. Note the use of byteswap. This is necessary if you cpu architecture endianness is mismatched.